# Term for Values that are Separated By Periods

Tags: terminology

Examples: ***12.3.2*** OR ***192.168.15.100***

What would be the right term for the values that are separated by the periods?

E.g.: The 2nd *XXX* of ***192.168.15.100*** = ***168***. Or the 3rd *XXX* OF ***12.3.2*** = ***2***.

The idea of the word is similar to ***Compartment***/***Part***/***location***.

Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Comment: 'Second *period-delimited* value' describes it completely, but is a bit of a mouthful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an IP address, that's the second *octet*. In everything else, that's the second *section* or simply the second *number*.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Often times, Numbers like this are formatted for a particular reason. For example, dates may be formatted with a period: “YYYY.MM.DD” in which case, you refer to each grouping as what it stands for. The same can be said of software version numbers: “MR.mR.Mr.mr.b” (Major Release, minor Release, Major revision, minor revision, build number).

Comment: @HalosGhost yes, but you are answering a different question there. This question here is specifically not talking about dates or version numbers (or IPs, for that matter). It is a most generic question, and so it gets the most generic answer.

Comment: I only wanted to qualify yaur answer because one example the OP gave (12.3.2) looked a little like a version number.

Comment: @HalosGhost yes my intention for this question was specifically targeted towards version numbering. What is the best word to call eat "group" of numbers. First "group", second "group"?

Comment: @Ryan if you are speaking about a version number, then it is likely best to refer to each group by what it actually represents (as in my last comment). However, you could say something like each “group” or “set."